# change color schema of facebook fb:login-button

Tags: facebook, fbml, xfbml

I am using facebook social plugin fb:login (new version) and here is my code.

```
<fb:login-button show-faces="true" perms="email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream"></fb:login-button>
```

I have a dark back ground in my page, so when user is logged on I can’t see user name as text is dark. 
So how do i set text color to be white?
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
<fb:login-button show-faces="true" perms="email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream" data-colorscheme="dark"></fb:login-button>
```

You can simply use *data-colorscheme="dark"* as with the Like button (undocumented option)